# Modal blocking dialog in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, openlayers, blocking

I'm developing Openlayers toolbar in Javascript with jQuery and jQuery UI.

One feature that I want to implement is Adding points to the map.

In openLayers you have to listen for event called 'sketchcomplete'.

```
layer.events.on({
    'sketchcomplete': onPointAdded
});
```

The problem is in onPointAdded callback. This callback should return true or false. True mean that the point should be added to the map and false means cancel adding this point to the map.

Now the callback looks like this:

```
onPointAdded = function(feature) {
  var f = feature.feature;
  var result = false;
  $('#dialog-point-add').dialog({
    modal : true,
    buttons : {
      'Add point' : function() {
        result = true;
        $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      'Cancel' : function() {
        result = false;
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });
  return result;
};
```

The problem is that this dialog doesn't block the executing code. I'm asking You How to handle this situation? I want to show dialog to the user with confirmation for adding the point.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you are not going to be able to do this with the jquery ui dialog. The vanilla js confirm box should work though.

Answer (score 0):

The function can not block, because JavaScript is single threaded and nothing else could be executed. Why don't you just add the logic, you want to call if the the function returns true, to the 'Add point' callback?

**EDIT:**
a "normal" JavaScript confirm dialog would block:

```
onPointAdded = function(feature) {
  return confirm("Sure?");
};
```

Comment: What do You mean add the logic? You mean to change the code that invoke this callback? If Yes this mean I have to digg in the OpenLayers code and change it but I prefer not to touch the library. Can You explain what is on your mind by saying "add the logic"? Thank You.

Comment: I don't know open layers and thought you would call some of your code when the function returns true. So my suggestion was to just move the code (or call) to the jQuery UI callback. Got that wrong, sorry.

Comment: This solution ofcourse block, but I need to display on my dialog box form with name input for just added point and when user press Save/Confirm then send Ajax post with coordinates and name from this form. When user click "Cancel" I need to delete the point. I found a solution for this with diffrent openlayers callback. Thank You very much...

Comment: You should post your solution then.